# HyperSnips / hsnips in Visual Studio Code: Create snippets that processes multiple parameters

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Sick of using try and error on this (promising) VS Code addon, so I came to this place.

I wanna create a **snippet for HyperSnips**, that can do the following:

**Process multiple inputs and input types**

Those input parameters should accept any alphanumerical input, also special characters like commas, semicolons and blank/space characters.

**Tab stops should jump to the next parameter**
The only exception to above mentioned input types should be tab stops - pressing this button should jump to the next input parameter.

**Nice to have**:
The input parameter input fields should disappear from the editor screen once the snippet's being finalized. I wanna only see them in the processed result.

This is, what I got so far.
At the moment on the keyup-event the input will be assigned to the next parameter variable.
Meaning my input ABC would turn into the parameters:
A
B
C

When pasting text from somewhere the input is assigned to the parameter, but since this kinda sucks, I want to be able to enter any string there and make a tabstop jump to the next input parameter.

```
snippet xtParamFun "Multi-Param Fun"


$1 $2 $3 

``      


    let arr1 = t[2].split(',');     
    let result = `My first two params ${t[0]} || ${t[1]}\n`;  
    
    if( (arr1.length > 0) )
        for (let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
                if (i>0)
                    result += `, ${arr1[i]}\n`
                else 
                    result += `Content: ${arr1[i]}\n`
    }   

    rv = result;
``
endsnippet
```